# CSS Positioning nested ul and display flex issue

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a vertical show and hide button mene.

I tried to achieve that when the "Cities" square is clicked, the ul with class `nested-ul` will be shown as it supposed to be. But the issue is I can't really position the li with class `nested-li` within the `.parent` ul, so the `nested-li` would be automatically changing lines. I've tried `flex-wrap:wrap`, that would just make the `nested-li` go straight down in one line. I want it to display vertically as normal and auto wrap down to the next line if it hits the `max-width` of the parent width.

```js
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
  $('.radio').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.nested-ul').show();
    } else {
      $('.nested-ul').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
}

.child {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

label p {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.radio {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.nested-ul {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  max-height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  left: calc(-100% - 55px);
}

.nested-li {
  min-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.radio:checked+label,
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ff0088;
}

.radio:checked+label>p,
label:hover>p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child">
    <input type="radio" id="colors" class="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="colors">
      <p>Colors</p>
    </label></li>
  <li class="child">
    <input type="radio" id="cities" class="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="cities">
      <p>Cities</p>
    </label>
    <ul class="nested-ul" style="display:none">
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>New York</p>
        </label></li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Calfornia</p>
        </label></li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Beijing</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Shanghai</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Tokyo</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Copenhagen</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Berlin</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>London</p>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('.radio').on('click', function() {
  $('.radio').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.nested-ul').show();
    } else {
      $('.nested-ul').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100%;
}

.parent {
  width: 450px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
  position:relative;
}

.child {
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

label {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  float: left;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  text-align: center;
}

label p {
  margin-top: 35px;
}

.radio {
  display: none;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.nested-ul {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 130px;
  max-height: inherit;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nested-li {
  min-width: 120px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  width:auto;
}

.radio:checked+label,
label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ff0088;
}

.radio:checked+label>p,
label:hover>p {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
  <li class="child">
    <input type="radio" id="colors" class="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="colors">
      <p>Colors</p>
    </label></li>
  <li class="child">
    <input type="radio" id="cities" class="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="cities">
      <p>Cities</p>
    </label>
    <ul class="nested-ul" style="display:none">
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>New York</p>
        </label></li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Calfornia</p>
        </label></li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Beijing</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Shanghai</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Tokyo</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Copenhagen</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>Berlin</p>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li class="nested-li">
        <label for="">
          <p>London</p>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It is almost how I wanted, I also forgot to mentioned, how do I keep the `parent` height expanding as the `nested-li` goes further down?

Comment: If you don't change HTML struct, You can't make "parent" auto height. but if you make for mobile web you can use height 100% with small change

Comment: Alright, I will try to change the HTML structure. Thanks!